# Contain check in Enum values

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can contain check against Enum values can be made?

```
class MyEnum(Enum):
    foo = 'FOO'
    bar = 'BAR'
```

I have already tried:

```
'zzz' in  class.__members__.values()
```

Could you point me the way?

Comment: outside the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the set of all values of the `Enum` and check using `in` membership operation

```
enum_values = {e.value for e in MyEnum}
print('FOO' in enum_values)
print('zzz' in enum_values)
```

The output will be

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can list and check the values like this:

```
def checkIfValueContainsInEnum(value):
    enumValues = [item.value for item in MyEnum]  # [4, 5, 6]
    if value in enumValues:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```